# How to run custom js code only for 1 component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know, is it possible to run script only for 1 component?

In my code I have imported 5 components

```
import React from 'react';

import Intro from './includes/Intro';
import Counter from './includes/Counter';
import Feedback from  './includes/Feedback';
import FeedbackAll from './includes/FeedbackAll';
import Faq from './includes/Faq';

class Home extends React.Component {

   render() {
        return(
            <main>
                <Intro />
                <Counter />
                <Feedback />
                <FeedbackAll />
                <Faq />
            </main>
         )
     }
 }

export default Home
```

So I have some script which I want to run only for the component `<Counter />`

When I write that script inside of that component, it runs in every single component of my project.

This is the file `Counter.js`

```
import React from 'react';

const Counter = () => {
    return (
        <section id="benefits">

        </section>
    );
};

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        let hT = document.querySelector("#benefits").offsetTop;

        alert (hT)
    });


export default Counter
```

When I navigate another page, on scroll the script still works and looking for the element #benefits, and shows error.

So I need to run that script only inside of the component `Counter.js`

Please help me to do that!

Comment: Please explain more what behavior you want. It would help if you draw out the different pages you want to display and what they should look like.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Currently I am having a bug, because in Counter.js there is an element which has id, and when I move to another component, the script is looking for that id and don't find. So if I run my script only for that component, the bug will be fixed

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in my script there is let x=document.querySelector("#benefits").offsetTop; and when I move to another page, the script can not find #benefits and shows error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a complete code example that illustrates the error. Be sure to paste the exact error and indicate which line causes it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done!

Comment: Thank you for the additional code. However, it is still incomplete because there are several undefined names: `Intro`, `Feedback`, etc. Either remove these, if they do not help illustrate your question, or add enough code so that anyone can copy and paste your code then run it themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor `counter.js` as class component. Trick is to move event listeners inside class definition and remove event listeners when un-mounting the class.

Now only in the pages you user `<Counter />`, scroll listeners are attached and it gets removed when `<Counter />` component is un-mounted.

Solution here

[image: Edit 6w30wwqwxw]

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect!